# Hands Free Camera to record footage for Youtube?

Tags: video-camera, video-capture

### Explanation

I want to start vlogging, but I don't want to hold a camera all day.

I have the following preferences for the camera:

- Hands Free
- Easy to record with HD
- Can easily record where I am looking
- HD 720p @ 30 fps lowest preferred
- Under $300
- Chest mounted unless there's a head camera which is unnoticeable
- Would prefer if the camera is unnoticeable (I'm shy of the idea of recording in public)
- Weight: I'm not sure to be honest but anything under 5lbs sounds good.
- Would appreciate if it can last over 4 hours of recording.

What camera options do I have?

Comment: Not sure if I'm right but, any action-cam can answer positively to your requests no?

Comment: What about audio? You looking for high quality audio recording?

Comment: yeah, I would prefer if the mic wasnt visible, I was thinking I could leave the mic under my shrit or so.

Comment: Maybe the Samsung NX Mini 2.0, it'd be pretty visible though. (when you hold it out with your arm) But it does have a flip screen. $390 on Amazon.